# PHPUnit, Phar and No such file or directory

Tags: phpunit, phar

I installed PHPUnit using phar, as described here, http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/installation.html

When I execute `phpunit --version` it works fine.  When I try to execute a test however, it gives me the following error:

> PHP Warning:  require(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in (blah, blah, blah)...

The phar is installed in /usr/local/bin (as recommended), and I added this path to the include_path in the php.ini for the cli.

Any ideas?

Comment: how does your include path look like now?

Comment: cweiske, I backed out and installed using PEAR.  Problem solved.

Comment: either delete your question, or add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backed out and installed using PEAR.  This got the result I was looking for, but doesn't really answer the question.